# Abrir Panel con botón y regresar de nuevo - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms

Tengo una duda acerca de un código sobre los Paneles.

Quiero hacer que el botón "Home" abra el "homepnl" y que los demás botones hagan lo mismo, abran su respectivo panel, muy bien ya intente con el código:

```
homepnl.show()
```

El codito funciona correctamente, pero tengo un problema y es que cuando quiero volver a abrirlo, presiono el botón y no se abre de nuevo el panel, no se si hice algo mal ahí o me falta código ( aun soy un novato).

Desearía que me ayuden, no quiero cerrar el panel, quiero que se oculte y volver a mostrar cuando se oprima el botón, lo mismo con los otros paneles.

PSDT: no se si entendió, espero que si, si me pudieran ayudar, estaría eternamente agradecidos. ( aun soy un novato, con muchas ganas de aprender :D)

[image: Imagen del programa:]

Comment: ¿Con qué código cierras el panel?

Comment: solo puse ese linea de codigo para mostrar, no lo estoy ocultando, todavía..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes alternar la visiblilidad. Si está visible, lo esconde, si no lo está lo muestra:

```
private sub button1_Click(sender as Object, e as System.EventArgs)
    if homepnl.Visible then
      homepnl.Hide()
    else
      homepnl.Show()
    end if
end sub
```

Comment: muchas gracias 